Patio door (installed), it's a right-hand opening door but we need a left-hand opening door
I had sliding patio doors installed a few days ago. I had Home Depot do it. They're standard "door on the floor" Home Depot doors, not custom. The door is right-hand opening but we need a left-hand opening door. It's my fault for not noticing this when I picked out the door.
There are 2 sliding doors so they both open. One idea I had was sliding the front right-hand opening door all the way to the left end of the track and sliding the left hand opeing door all the way to the right. But the doors can only go half way, they can't slide past each other. Is there some way to make them slide past each other?
If not, is there any other way to change the doors so that the right-hand door opens on the left instead of the right? Is it possible to remove the doors completely, then put the left-hand opening door on the front track, and the right-hand opening door on the second track (where the left-hand door was)?
I don't want to buy/install a new door. We can't afford it.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Maybe, but pictures of top and bottom of the doors/tracks plus any handles/locks on the doors will help.  There might stuff that is not removable that stops the change.   The store/installers might know more, if this is possible.

Major "it depends", I think. In some models the stationary door is just a movable door fixed in place, and outside of having to move stops, re-weatherstrip, and come up with your own handle and latch it's simple. Others use more dedicated parts.

If both doors open, why is there a problem?

This sounds like you want to have the doors open in the center. Highly unlikely. At a minimum, the meeting rails (center interlocks)would have to be reversed and the bottom rail switched to keep the wheels on the right track.

There are 2 doors, both doors slide along a track, they don't swing open. They only slide about half way. They can't open in the middle.

Both doors open, yes but we want the door closest to the inside of the house to be on the left side.

Some sliding doors are universal handing, i.e. they can be installed in right hand or left hend opening.  Do you know what make/model of door you had installed?

It's a Farley patio door, 5 ft.
Model # PPD5068XX|Store SKU # 1000850833

According to Farley, this door is reversible.
